# Accessing cookies in nunjucks template

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, nunjucks

I am currently working on a project that utilizes the nunjucks templating engine. I have run into an issue with preserving the UI state. Currently, I load the page with data that depends on a set cookie. However, when a user submits an ajax post request the frontend is restored and the cookie isn't checked. So, I lose the ability to apply any logic based on this cookie value. I solved it by adding the cookie value to a hidden input and ignoring it on the post, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this sort of thing? Otherwise I will end up having to ignore hidden inputs in my api all of the time.

FRONT END HIDDEN INPUT

```
<form id="facetform">
  <input hidden name="BoostParameters" id="BoostParameters" value="frame_fit={{framefit}}"/>
</form>
```

API IGNORING THE INPUT

```
public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> BuildFacetDictonaryFromForm(JObject jObject)
        {
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> facetDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            foreach (var element in jObject.SelectToken("Facets").ToString().Split('&'))
            {
                if (element.Contains("BoostParameters")) {
                    continue;
                }
                var input = element.Split('=');

                AddFacetToDictionary(ref facetDictionary, input[0], input[1]);
            }
            return facetDictionary;
        }
```

EXTRACTING THE VALUE IN THE TEMPLATE

```
{% set framefit = postdata.facets.split("BoostParameters=frame_fit%3D")[1].split("%25")[0].split("&")[0] %}
```

Comment: I don't understand your issue exactly. There is no problem to get cookie values: you can extend Nunjuck with [custom filter](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#custom-filters) or [global](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#addglobal) function to achive it.

Comment: So, you're saying I could make a getCookieValue global function? Would that function replace the template variables on an ajax post request? That's my issue. The page works fine on the first load, but it's subsequent ajax calls that mess up the page. Does that make sense? tbh I don't know much about filters or global functions.

Comment: `Would that function replace the template variables on an ajax post request?` Nunjucks is a render engine. It doesn't send ajax requests or update page on some cause by itself. However, Nunjucks could be extented to read cookie values or to receive data through ajax request while render.

Comment: So basically, I need to find someway to access the cookies from the page in the node side of my code correct? If I could avoid having to send the cookie value in a hidden input that would be ideal. I just don't how else to send the cookie from the page to the server side code.

Comment: Hmm, are you using Nunjucks on server-side? I suppose that you are using C# on server-side and Nunjucks on client side.

Comment: the nunjucks templates are on the client, node on the server, and c# on the server. I am using both node and c#.

Comment: `I just don't how else to send the cookie from the page to the server side code`: cookies is sended with each request, so you don't need to pass their as hidden input value. For `http`-node server check `req.headers.cookies`. If you are use Express then install [cookie-parser](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html) and check req.cookies.